# How do I do this autumagically in emacs

Tags: emacsclient

How do I get emacs to automatically format a large text file like section a
to section b. I have tried using notepad++ and a macro, but it just froze my computer

```
section a

words    wordss
wordsss    wordssss
wordssss    wordsssss
wordsssss    wordssssss

to

section b

words
wordss
wordsss
wordssss
wordsssss
wordssssss
```

Comment: How about placing your cursor at the beginning of the word "section"?:  `M-x replace-string RET C-q TAB RET C-q C-j RET` assuming those are tabs.  If they are spaces then count how many spaces and use that instead of `C-q TAB`.

Comment: is there a way to distinguish tabs from spaces if I didn't create the file?

Comment: `M-x whitespace-mode`

Comment: it's four spaces so I would

Comment: It would be perhaps better to write a more descriptive title for your question.

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression will work with both tabs and spaces and also with a variable number of them. Type `M-x replace-regexp RET \s-+ RET Q-q C-j RET`, this will replace any sequence of one or more whitespace characters with a single newline, see the [emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexps.html#Regexps) for details.

Answer (score 0):

As @npostavs points out in a comment above, `M-x whitespace-mode` is very helpful to visually distinguish between tabs and spaces.

If it were four (4) spaces, instead of tabs between the words, then:  Place the cursor at the beginning of the word "section" [or simply *before* the first occurrence to be replaced] and type `M-x replace-string RET     RET C-q C-j RET` .  The gap between the two `RET` are four (4) spaces.

If it were tabs, instead of spaces between the words, then:  Place the cursor at the beginning of the word "section" [or simply *before* the first occurrence to be replaced] and type `M-x replace-string RET C-q TAB RET C-q C-j RET`

---

To limit the search to a specific region, select the region and type `M-x narrow-to-region`.  When done, type `M-x widen`.

Comment: Using a regular expression you don't need to know if they are spaces or tabs and can also work with a variable number of spaces

Comment: @matteol -- Please write up an alternative answer.

Comment: I posted an answer.